# I don't use Google Plus – why do I have followers on my Google Account?

Tags: google-plus, google-account, google-account-profile

When I do a *Privacy Checkup* from my Google Account page, and examine the first setting *1. Control what others see about you*, I see that I have a number of "Followers".

I am wondering why this happens, even though I don't have a Google Plus profile – at least not an active profile that I know of. When I go to Google Plus, I am met by an "Account upgrade to Google Plus" screen.

Questions:

1. Why do I have these "followers"?
2. How can I see who they are?
3. Most importantly, how can I remove/block the followers, and hinder new followers?

Comment: You can add an email address to a Google+ Circle without that email address having a G+ profile. (At least, you used to.)

Comment: I'd answer, but this question is locked for some reason. The only way I know is to view each follower's profile and block them. They're then removed as a follower. You can unblock, and they won't be re-added as a follower. This, however, is extremely tedious to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*Account upgrade*" screen is something that Google+ put onto accounts about a year ago.  It is asking if you wish to upgrade from the old Google+ screen layout to the new layout.

To paraphrase, it is not asking "*Do you wish to have a Google+ account?*", just "*Do you want the new display for your existing Google+ account?*".

Go past that screen, look at the People link on the left of the screen (New layout).  You will be able to see the identity of your followers.

If you wish, you may then block their profiles.

From your Profile link, you can adjust your privacy settings to dissuade others.

Comment: The *Account upgrade* screen says "Join Google+ by creating your public profile". The next step is to "Follow things". Are you sure that it's just an "upgrade view" screen and not creation of a profile?

Comment: Yes, that's a different screen.  You can still go on and see who is following you though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hinder or remove followers, but if you never post anything to them, they will never see anything.

The only things they will ever see is what you post public, and what you post explicitly to them.

They have no different standing than anyone else in the world, it just would give them a ping *if* you post something to them.

So you shouldn't worry about it.